# cassandra 2.2 CQl Shell supports python 2.7

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cql

Error I am get when trying to start cql Shell

```
>cqlsh
CQL Shell supports only Python 2.7
>
```

I have installed python2.7 but it is still giving the same error.
do i have to set path some were?
i have installed Cassandra 2.2 from datastax suing this command

```
sudo yum install dsc22
```

Comment: cqlsh will use the python interpreter from your path. What does running ` python --version` show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your distribution and its version you cannot change the default python version of the system without breaking the system. If you have Python 2.7 installed then its interpreter is probably on your path as `python2.7`.

Try running `python2.7 --version`. If that gives you an output like `Python 2.7.x` you are good. Just edit the `cqlsh` script and replace `python` with `python2.7` at the beginning of the only code line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use python 2.7 but be aware of  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to post as a comment. If you encounter same problem as @andrewdeal and you [installed Python 2.7 side-by-side](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/) (a must on CentOS 6 which requires Python 2.6), you need site-packages in your Python 2.7 install.

As root:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/README
rmdir /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

You can now run `cqlsh`

Answer (score -1):

I tried doing that change from python to python2.7 and then got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 152, in <module>
from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling
ImportError: No module named cqlshlib
```