# cqlsh does not work for Cassandra 3.11X and Python 2.7.X

Tags: python, cassandra, debian

When i Install **Cassandra 3.11X** and **Python 2.7.X** in **Debian 8.8**, the Cqlsh does not start.
I get the following error.

```
debian@vm-184:/opt/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin$ ./cqlsh
```

Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on **PYTHONPATH**.
You might try "`pip install cassandra-driver`".

```
Python: /usr/local/bin/python
Module load path: ['/opt/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/../lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/opt/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/../lib/futures-2.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/opt/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.7.0.post0-2481531.zip/cassandra-driver-3.7.0.post0-2481531', '/opt/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

> Error: can't decompress data; zlib not available

How do we resolve this

Answer (score 1):

On RedHat 7x - Install the following packages:

***# yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel***

Then...

***# vi .../Python-2.7.13/Modules/Setup***

uncomment the line:
...

***zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz***

AND (re-)compile python source:

***# cd .../Python-2.7.13/Modules/***

***# ./configure***

***# make***

**# make install**

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Is the `zlib` library install?
please install `zlib` first.

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally comes when your machine has Python 2.6 or below.
Check the answer over here [cassandra 2.2 CQl Shell supports python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314104/cassandra-2-2-cql-shell-supports-python-2-7) on how to start cqlsh using python 2.7

Quoting - "Depending on your distribution and its version you cannot change the default python version of the system without breaking the system." 
I would recommend you to choose Debian version that uses Python2.7x natively.